# Can adding data to a file compress it by more?

Tags: algorithm, compression

Let's say I have a 10MB file that I can compress to 5MB. Are there situations where you could add data to the file and cause it to compress to smaller than 5MB?

Edit: And just to be clear by adding data to the file I mean appending data, not adding to the middle of the file.

Comment: I think to clarify, you don't care about how the data is added, so long as there exists a method for you to decompress it and get your original data back (and know it's extents what whatnot)?

Comment: The more I think about it, the more certain I become that the answer is "no".  Otherwise, the compression algorithm would already be adding this data for you and removing it silently without your knowledge, to give you the smallest possible size.

Comment: @MooingDuck: What you said is true for Kolmogorov complexity, which is the notion of "compression" that has all the nice properties that you can reason about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To your original question:

Yes.

Notice that every 5MB file appears as a noncontiguous bitwise subsequence of the file `(01)^(41943040)`, which is twice the size and compresses very well.  Indeed, you can pick exactly one bit from each of the 41943040 `01`'s.

The trick here is that, from the "padded" file, you can't recover the original.  All 5MB files "pad" to the same string of bits.

To your revised question:

Still "yes," but it's close enough to "no" for all practical purposes.  I don't think this can happen with gzip.  However, if you compress using a Burrows-Wheeler transform followed by run-length encoding, appending to the string can alter the order of the string's cyclic shifts and thereby, by pure coincidence, result in a string that compresses better.

Comment: Your method of "adding data to the file" is very strange.  Usually "adding data to file" means appending some block of bytes to it.

Answer (score 0):

With dictionary type compression, the are models that have an entry for every prefix of any given entry (LZW, for one), and others that do not (e.g., LZMW).
If for the latter an extension of, say, a file of 10^7 bytes can use an entry with a cheaper encoding than any encoding of the prefix to the end of the original file, the compressed file will be shorter.
(With LZMW and 10^7 identical bytes, I expect an entry for two bytes after encoding the first two, another for four, eight, … 2^22. Appending (3*2^22 - 10^7) allows finishing with just one more "2^22 code" - codes for 10^7 bytes left as an …)